# Reload Same Page But on list box selection Changed Event Windows Phone 7 update

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Here is an example of what I want to see: http://www.mywork.com.au/blog/how-to-create-a-simple-facebook-style-sidebar-menu-using-only-css-and-minimal-javascript/

For I am displaying category_headings(where their are news feed, messages etc are) in a list box. What I want when the user selects a category and a changed event fires then it should display related details of that category on same page.

Here is my code Class1.cs

```
   public class RootObject
    {
        public string category_id { get; set; }
        public string category_heading { get; set; }
        public string detail { get; set; }
    }
```

Code in MainPage.xaml.cs

```
  namespace testApp
 {

 public partial class mainpage : PhoneApplicationPage
 {
    private bool _isSettingsOpen = false;

     RootObject obj = new RootObject();

     public mainpageUI()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += mainpage;
    }       

    public void mainpage(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("JSON STRING"));
        webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadStringCompleted);
    }


    public void webClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        RootObject[] jobj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject[]>(e.Result);       


        listBox1.ItemsSource = jobj;

    }

    **private void on_click(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) //listbox selectionchanged event
    {
        //what should I do here so that every time user will select different category it will display details   on same page.

    }**

  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  //Code for event which opens Facebook like menu pane
    {

        if (_isSettingsOpen)
        {
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "SettingsClosedState", true);
            _isSettingsOpen = false;
        }
        else
        {
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "SettingsOpenState", true);
            _isSettingsOpen = true;
        }

    }        
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To filter the items based on the user selection, first save off the data to a property. Then when the selection occurs filter the property and reattach. Note there is no need to reload the page, just change the binding of the control to use a new list which was filtered.

```
private RootObject[] InitialFeed { get; set; } 


public void webClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   InitialFeed = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject[]>(e.Result);       

  listBox1.ItemsSource = InitialFeed ;

}

private void on_click(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) //listbox selectionchanged event
{
   listBox1.ItemsSource = InitialFeed.Where(itm => itm.SomeSubProperty == listbox1.SelectedValue)
                                     .ToList();

}
```

What is happening above is that the original data is being saved off and shown with no filters. Then the user selects something from another listbox which causes us to filter out whatever they selected and *rebind* `lisBox1` with a new set of data to display.

Note that this will work but is not an MVVM way of doing it. I give a quick example of MVVM and basic binding in Xaml on my blog article [Xaml: ViewModel Main Page Instantiation and Loading Strategy for Easier Binding.](http://omegacoder.com/?p=1017)

Comment: and what if I have to pass category_id and selected index foreach selection made in listbox, and then based on that have to display details on the same page?

Comment: @user3183503 you need to look into binding those values to a ViewModel or a centralized location. Once that is done, one simply accesses all that information and processes them accordingly in the on_click I showed above. That VM (view model) can be passed to different pages and used by the pages if this is a navigation situation as well. You have the basics of control usage, but using an MVVM motif *greatly* enhances the power of WPF/WP8/Silverlight/Win RT; hence you need to read up/investigate. :-)